# MPL placeholder replacement in default template parameter

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, boost-mpl

I'm having some troubles understanding MPL placeholders.
Could someone please explain me why this code fails to compile?

I would expect the number 0, 1 & 2 to be printed but it seems the placeholder doesn't get replaced with the actual type when the compiler tries to determine the type of the default template parameter of Wrapper.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/mpl/inherit.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/inherit_linearly.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/int.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>

template <typename T> struct Traits;

template<> struct Traits<int>  { typedef boost::mpl::int_<0> type; };
template<> struct Traits<char> { typedef boost::mpl::int_<1> type; };
template<> struct Traits<bool> { typedef boost::mpl::int_<2> type; };

template <typename T, typename Type=typename Traits<T>::type > struct Wrapper
{
    Wrapper() { std::cout << "Value: " << Type::value << std::endl; }

    T value;
};

int main()
{
    typedef boost::mpl::inherit_linearly<
                boost::mpl::vector<int, char, bool>,
                boost::mpl::inherit<boost::mpl::_1, Wrapper<boost::mpl::_2> > >::type Object;

    Object obj;

    return 0;
}
```

This is the error from gcc-4.1.2 (I know... old compiler at work)

```
# g++4 -I ../boost test.cpp -o test
test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:24: error: invalid use of undefined type 'struct Traits<mpl_::arg<2> >'
test.cpp:7: error: declaration of 'struct Traits<mpl_::arg<2> >'
test.cpp:24: error: template argument 2 is invalid
test.cpp:24: error: template argument 2 is invalid
test.cpp:24: error: template argument 2 is invalid
test.cpp:24: error: expected initializer before 'Object'
test.cpp:26: error: 'Object' was not declared in this scope
test.cpp:26: error: expected `;' before 'obj'
```

**EDIT:**
After Acorbe's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045431/mpl-placeholder-replacement-in-default-template-parameter?#answer-13055739) below I've made a variant of my example program to show why his proposed solution does not fit my needs. This clarifies what I'm after. In this case I would expect the text TYPE_A, TYPE_B, TYPE_A to be printed. The g++ error is the same.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/mpl/inherit.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/inherit_linearly.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/int.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>

enum WrapperType { TYPE_A, TYPE_B };

template <typename T> struct Traits;

template<> struct Traits<int>  { typedef boost::mpl::int_<TYPE_A> type; };
template<> struct Traits<char> { typedef boost::mpl::int_<TYPE_B> type; };
template<> struct Traits<bool> { typedef boost::mpl::int_<TYPE_A> type; };

template <typename T, typename Type=typename Traits<T>::type > struct Wrapper;

template <typename T>
struct Wrapper<T, boost::mpl::int_<TYPE_A> >
{
    Wrapper() : value (0) { std::cout << "TYPE_A" << std::endl; }

    T value;
};

template <typename T>
struct Wrapper<T, boost::mpl::int_<TYPE_B> >
{
    Wrapper() { std::cout << "TYPE_B" << std::endl; }

    T value;
};

int main()
{
    typedef boost::mpl::inherit_linearly<
                boost::mpl::vector<int, char, bool>,
                boost::mpl::inherit<boost::mpl::_1, Wrapper<boost::mpl::_2> > >::type Object;

    Object obj;

    return 0;
}
```

This is the error from gcc-4.5.4

```
# g++ -I ../boost test.cpp -o test
test.cpp: In functie ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:37:79: fout: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct Traits<mpl_::arg<2> >’
test.cpp:9:34: fout: declaration of ‘struct Traits<mpl_::arg<2> >’
test.cpp:37:79: fout: template argument 2 is invalid
test.cpp:37:81: fout: template argument 2 is invalid
test.cpp:37:83: fout: template argument 2 is invalid
test.cpp:37:91: fout: expected initializer before ‘Object’
test.cpp:39:9: fout: ‘Object’ was not declared in this scope
test.cpp:39:16: fout: expected ‘;’ before ‘obj’
```

This is (partially) the error from clang++-3.1:

```
test.cpp:15:50: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'Traits<mpl_::arg<2> >'
    template <typename T, typename Type=typename Traits<T>::type > struct Wrapper;
                                                 ^
test.cpp:37:57: note: in instantiation of default argument for 'Wrapper<mpl_::arg<2> >' required here
                    boost::mpl::inherit<boost::mpl::_1, Wrapper<boost::mpl::_2> > >::type Object;
                                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:9:34: note: template is declared here
    template <typename T> struct Traits;
```

Comment: For what it worth, I have 2 suggestions: 1. aren't you forgetting to do `typedef typename` instead of just `typename`? 2. You don't need `<T, Type>` in `Wrapper` constructor declaration.

Comment: @Acorbe: `typename` is only needed for dependent names, which isn't the case here. The second point however is valid, it's actually an error to say `<T, Type>` in the constructor IIRC.

Comment: @Acorbe @Xeo: Thanks for your replies. I didn't know the `<T, Type>` was invalid. I've removed it from the constructor declaration and this has reduced the errors a bit. the 'invalid use of undefined type 'struct Traits<mpl_::arg<2> >'' remains unfortunately.

Comment: @CodeWarrior, nice. Please update the code and the error list.

Comment: @Acorbe: Original post updated :-)

Comment: @CodeWarrior, please consider the answer below.

Comment: Indeed, now I'm not very convinced with the way partial specialization is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allright... I seem to have cracked it...
As often, an extra level of abstraction did the trick.

I created a metafunction class (genWrapper) which is passed to mpl::apply1 together with the placeholder. The metafunction in there would then return the expected wrapper type.

Here is the resulting program (the 2nd version).
Thanks to all for the help and pointers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/mpl/apply.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/inherit.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/inherit_linearly.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/int.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>

enum WrapperType { TYPE_A, TYPE_B };

template <typename T> struct Traits;

template<> struct Traits<int>  { typedef boost::mpl::int_<TYPE_A> type; };
template<> struct Traits<char> { typedef boost::mpl::int_<TYPE_B> type; };
template<> struct Traits<bool> { typedef boost::mpl::int_<TYPE_A> type; };

template <typename T, typename Type = typename Traits<T>::type> struct Wrapper;

template <typename T>
struct Wrapper<T, boost::mpl::int_<TYPE_A> >
{
    Wrapper() : value (0) { std::cout << "TYPE_A" << std::endl; }

    T value;
};

template <typename T>
struct Wrapper<T, boost::mpl::int_<TYPE_B> >
{
    Wrapper() { std::cout << "TYPE_B" << std::endl; }

    T value;
};

struct genWrapper
{
    template <typename T>
    struct apply
    {
        typedef Wrapper<T> type;
    };
};

int main()
{
    typedef boost::mpl::inherit_linearly<
                boost::mpl::vector<int, char, bool>,
                boost::mpl::inherit<boost::mpl::_1, boost::mpl::apply1<genWrapper, boost::mpl::_2> > >::type Object;

    Object obj;

    return 0;
}
```

This is the resulting output:

```
# g++4 -I ../boost test.cpp -o test
# ./test
TYPE_A
TYPE_B
TYPE_A
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a little change in your code splitting the `typedef` induced by the default template parameter in two simpler `typedef`s.

Consider this:

```
template < typename T , typename Super_Type = Traits<T> > struct Wrapper
{ 
     typedef typename Super_Type::type Type;
     Wrapper() { std::cout << "Value: " << Type::value << std::endl; }

     T value;
};
```

This way it compiles. My suspect is that your orginal expression (although correct) is *somehow* too complicated to be correctly expanded by the compiler.

Comment: Thanks! That does indeed compile fine, but it doesn't fit what I want to do. I want to be able to partially specialize Wrapper on the 2nd template parameter. It seems I simplified my example too much. I'll update my original post to show what I'm after... I tried to compile this with g++-4.5.4 and clang++-3.1 as well and get similar error messages. I don't think the code is too complex for the compiler but more that I do not grasp the intricacies of MPL placeholders yet..

Comment: Consider that now you are HEAVILY changing your question. Please, put your new code into a new question or, at least, in a "EDIT" section. Your behavior, otherwise, would look pretty disrespectful to ones who voluntarily read and worked on your code. This is not the way it works!

Comment: Consider this meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2081/solve-the-modified-question-problem

Comment: Thanks for you help and answers. The last thing I want to do is being disrespectful to people that try to help me. As you suggested, I've put the modified example program in an EDIT section. As far as I see, the original question still stands and the problem reported is still the same therefore I think it would be confusing to create another question about the same issue.

Comment: Very nice, thank you! And nice question! I will consider it as soon as I can.